# How to display questions only for some few selected tags?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to be able to select a few tags on Stack Overflow and be restricted to only questions and answers matching these Tags. I'm fine with inaccuracy upto a certain extent. Can you please help me out with this ?

Please correct me if this question is off-topic for this discussion site

Comment: You can at least choose some favorite tags (or some to be excluded), filter with one of these, and you'll see other matching favorites highlighted.

Comment: That is in the [Help]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

Comment: related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags

Answer (score 2):

You can create a URL with the tags you want to browse with this syntax:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just search for: `[tag a] or [tag b] or [tag c]`